# A more elegant REGEX? Possibly with positive/negative lookaheads/behinds?

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a REGEX here which is producing the desired effect but it's a bit clunky

https://regex101.com/r/WwxW6G/2

```
\(.*?, USA\)|\(USA, .*?\)|\(.*?, USA, .*?\)
```

Inputs:

```
Match Me! (USA, Europe)
Match Me! (Europe, USA)
Match Me! (Asia, USA, Europe)

Don't Match Me (USA)
Don't Match Me USA
USA Don't Match Me
Don't Match Me (USA)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this without several ORs - I don't need a clean bracket to be matched, I just need the right lines to be matched in a check.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you add your regex to the question?

Comment: Please define "clunky". Look, [`\((?!(?1)\))(?:[^()]+, )?(USA)(?:, [^()]+)?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/qO0ZgN/1) will do, but isn't it more cryptic?

Comment: Try `\([^)]*?USA(?:(?=,)|(?<=, ...))[^)]*\)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/WwxW6G/4

Answer (score 0):

Using a single alternation to check for a comma before or after USA between parenthesis you might use:

[`\(.*?(?:\bUSA\s*,|,\s*USA\b).*?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/ztdVkr/1)

Answer (score 0):

In such cases - when a word could be delimited and one delimiter is a must and if the word has a known length - you could benefit from two positive lookarounds:

```
\([^)]*?USA(?:(?=,)|(?<=, ...))[^)]*\)
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WwxW6G/4)

This leads to a more quick matching.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** It's not that elegant, but I think it's complete :S.

I'll have a go to ;)

```
\((?=[^,)]*,)(?=(?:[^)]*, )?\bUSA\b(?=,|\)))(?:\w+,?\s*)+\)
```

It uses positive lookaheads to ensure there's a comma inside the parentheses (so it's at least two words), as well as the word `USA` (because I'm guessing that's a requirement - it's not stated in the Q). Then it simply allows any number of comma separated words inside the parentheses.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3pokih/4).

Comment: This will match `(Europe, NO USA)`.

Comment: @revo ...and yours will match `(Europe, USAland)` ;) I'll look into it :)